# Como puedo listar un objeto en el front

Tags: javascript

Hola me pidieron para un trabajo practico hacer esto

Un formulario de ciudad para registrar todas las ciudades necesarias:
CodigoCiudad,
DescripcionCiudad,
FechaEvento,
HoraEvento, con un boton
Botón Aceptar
Botón Volver

Un formulario para registrar un evento con los siguientes datos:
CodigoEvento,
DescripcionEvento,
CiudadEvento – una lista de todas las ciudades ya cargadas.,
con
Botón Aceptar y
Botón Volver

Un formulario Asistencia a evento para registrar la asistencia de las personas que asistirá al evento seleccionado

Evento – Una lista cargada con los eventos almacenados.
Botón nuevo evento que contendra
NombrePersona,
ApellidoPersona,
CédulaPersona,
DirecciónPersona,
TeléfonoPersona,
CiudadPersona – Una lista cargada con las ciudades almacenadas,

Mi duda es como  cargo   los datos de un objeto json en una lista en el front  como lo hago ?

Aca tengo el form del html de la primera pagina

```
    <form>
       <div class="container2">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="CodigoCiudadhelp" class="form-label">1. Codigo de Ciudad</label>
              <input type="CodigoCiudad" class="form-control" id="CodigoCiudad" name="CodigoCiudad" aria-describedby="CodigoCiudadhelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="Ciudadhelp" class="form-label">2. Ciudad</label>
              <input type="Ciudad" class="form-control" id="Ciudad" aria-describedby="Ciudadhelp" name="Ciudad">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="FechaEventohelp" class="form-label">3. Fecha de evento </label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="FechaEvento" aria-describedby="FechaEventohelp" name="FechaEvento">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="HoraEventohelp" class="form-label">4. Hora de Evento</label>
              <input type="time" class="form-control" id="HoraEvento" aria-describedby="HoraEventohelp" name="HoraEvento">
            </div>
            <div class="btn-c">
              <button type="submit"onclick="guardarDatos()"  class="btn btn-primary btn-enviar" style="text-decoration:none; color: white;"id="enviar">Aceptar</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-enviar"id="enviar"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="guardarDatos()" style="text-decoration:none; color: white;" href="FormAsistencia.html">Volver </a></button>  
           </div>
          </div>
   </form>
```

y esta seria la pagina donde tendria que cargarse el select con la ciudades cargadas

```
    <form>
       <div class="container2">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="CodigoEventohelp" class="form-label">1. Codigo de Evento</label>
              <input type="Nombre" class="form-control" id="CodigoEvento" name="CodigoEvento" aria-describedby="CodigoEventohelp">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="DescripcionEventohelp" class="form-label">2. Descripcion de Evento</label>
              <input type="apellido" class="form-control" id="DescripcionEvento" aria-describedby="DescripcionEventohelp" name="DescripcionEvento">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <select for="cedulahelp" class="form-label">
              <option type="ciudad" class="form-control" id="ciudad" aria-describedby="nombrehelp" name="ciudad">Seleccione un pais</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-c">
              <button type="submit"onclick="guardarDatos()"  class="btn btn-primary btn-enviar" style="text-decoration:none; color: white;"id="enviar">Aceptar</button>
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-enviar"id="enviar"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="guardarDatos()" style="text-decoration:none; color: white;" href="FormAsistencia.html">Volver </a></button>  
           </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi js  actualmente

```html
function guardarDatos() {
    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target));
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }),
      (location.href = "FormEventos.html");    }
```

Como uso ese data para mandar el en el front tengo que hacer un for por javascript para hacer el listado que me pide ? o tengo que usar el localstorage.

Comment: Saludos. Debes colocar más código; tanto de tu estructura html y demás que tienes para que te guíen. La sola exposición de lo que tienes que hacer y el código que pusiste no da idea de donde tienes el obstáculo que está deteniendo tu progreso.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. Creo que tu pregunta tiene mucha información que no es relevante al problema que enfrentas y eso tiende a confundir. Yo la leí y ya no sé si, al final, estás hablando de las ciudades, de los eventos o de la asistencia a los eventos. Dale una mirada a [ask], [mcve] y [edit] tu pregunta y enfócala en el problema específico que estás enfrentando, dando el contexto necesario para poder entender el problema. Eso aumentará tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas.

Comment: Ya tengo el objeto pero necesito que me guarde varias veces el array por que se me guarda, y a refrescar la pagina se borra lo que guarde en el array